# RabbitMQ cluster with docker on different servers

Tags: docker

I got this error when trying to configure RabbitMQ in a cluster different server.

root @ rabbitmq2: / # rabbitmqctl join_cluster rabbit @ rabbit1
Clustering node rabbit @ rabbitmq2 with rabbit @ rabbit1 ...
Error: Unable to connect to nodes [rabbit @ rabbit1]: nodedown

## DIAGNOSTICS

attempted to contact: [rabbit @ rabbit1]

rabbit @ rabbit1:
   * Unable to connect to epmd (port 4369) on rabbit1: NXDOMAIN (non-existing domain)

current node details:
- Node name: 'RabbitMQ-cli-47 @ rabbitmq2'
- Home dir: / var / lib / RabbitMQ
- Hash cookie: Q6urB / 4YJU5p5MdmILwyaw ==

I've tried everything and can not find a solution.
I believe that the problem is associated with the docker container, where a server 2 is not able to access the server 1.

Has anyone had this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You are not explaining how the Docker container was set up. I had the same issue with starting up the container with:

```
docker run --hostname rabbit1.example.com --add-host rabbit1.example.com:192.168.33.20 --add-host rabbit2.example.com:192.168.33.21 --name rabbit -p 15672:15672 -p 4369:4369 -p 5672:5672 -p 5671:5671 -p 25672:25672 -e RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE='some cookie' -d rabbitmq:3-management
```

RabbitMQ then named the node as `rabbit@rabbit1`, stripping off the domain from the hostname. The issue was fixed with creating the Docker container using hostnames without the domains:

```
docker run --hostname rabbit1 --add-host rabbit1:192.168.33.20 --add-host rabbit2:192.168.33.21 --name rabbit -p 15672:15672 -p 4369:4369 -p 5672:5672 -p 5671:5671 -p 25672:25672 -e RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE='some cookie' -d rabbitmq:3-management
```

Now `join_cluster rabbit@rabbit1` was successful on the rabbit2 container.

I also tried to make the node to join the cluster with the whole domain with `rabbitmqctl join_cluster rabbit@rabbit1.example.com`, this got me further but I was still facing hostname issues.